# How do I optimize this code?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have some powershell script with blocks:

```
$checkBox_1.Add_CheckStateChanged({
    if( $checkBox_1.Checked -or 
        $checkBox_2.Checked -or
        $checkBox_3.Checked -or
        $checkBox_4.Checked -or
        $checkBox_5.Checked -or
        $checkBox_6.Checked -or
        $checkBox_7.Checked -or
        $checkBox_8.Checked -or
        $checkBox_9.Checked -or
        $checkBox_10.Checked -or
        $checkBox_11.Checked -or
        $checkBox_12.Checked -or
        $checkBox_13.Checked -or
        $checkBox_14.Checked ) {
        $okButton.Enabled = $True
    }
    else {
        $okButton.Enabled = $False
    }
})
$checkBox_2.Add_CheckStateChanged({
    if( $checkBox_1.Checked -or 
        $checkBox_2.Checked -or
        $checkBox_3.Checked -or
        $checkBox_4.Checked -or
        $checkBox_5.Checked -or
        $checkBox_6.Checked -or
        $checkBox_7.Checked -or
        $checkBox_8.Checked -or
        $checkBox_9.Checked -or
        $checkBox_10.Checked -or
        $checkBox_11.Checked -or
        $checkBox_12.Checked -or
        $checkBox_13.Checked -or
        $checkBox_14.Checked ) {
        $okButton.Enabled = $True
    }
    else {
        $okButton.Enabled = $False
    }
})
```

and another twelve similar blocks.

Is the way to write this blocks in shorter, nicer way?

Comment: This might be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of all the checkboxes just once:

```ps
$checkboxes = Get-Variable checkBox_*
$checkboxes | ForEach {
    $_.Value.Add_CheckStateChanged({
        $okButton.Enabled = $True -in ($checkboxes | ForEach { $_.Value.Checked })
    })
}
```

In PS3.0+ the inner check could be simplified:

```ps
        $okButton.Enabled = $True -in $checkboxes.Value.Checked
```